# PHP Session Variables don't pass for some users, but pass fine for others

Tags: php, session-variables

I built a public-facing PHP application in multiple screens.  It tested fine on my personal desktop PC, but doesn't work on other PC's where the application is being tested.  All PC's are using Windows 10 and the browser is Firefox.  The permissions on the "tmp" folder on the Unix server are "755".
The SESSIONS section of the PHP.ini file on the server is as follows:

```
[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
session.save_handler = files

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
; As of PHP 4.0.1, you can define the path as:
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if you
; or your OS have problems with lots of files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle lots of sessions.
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
session.save_path = /tmp

; Whether to use cookies.
session.use_cookies = 1

; This option enables administrators to make their users invulnerable to
; attacks which involve passing session ids in URLs; defaults to 0.
; session.use_only_cookies = 1

; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
session.name = PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
session.auto_start = 0

; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

; The path for which the cookie is valid.
session.cookie_path = /

; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
session.cookie_domain =

; Handler used to serialize data.  php is the standard serializer of PHP.
session.serialize_handler = php

; Define the probability that the 'garbage collection' process is started
; on every session initialization.
; The probability is calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor,
; e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts
; on each request.

session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 100

; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

; NOTE: If you are using the subdirectory option for storing session files
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*
;       happen automatically.  You will need to do your own garbage
;       collection through a shell script, cron entry, or some other method.
;       For example, the following script would is the equivalent of
;       setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 1440 (1440 seconds = 24 minutes):
;          cd /path/to/sessions; find -cmin +24 | xargs rm

; PHP 4.2 and less have an undocumented feature/bug that allows you to
; to initialize a session variable in the global scope, albeit register_globals
; is disabled.  PHP 4.3 and later will warn you, if this feature is used.
; You can disable the feature and the warning separately. At this time,
; the warning is only displayed, if bug_compat_42 is enabled.

session.bug_compat_42 = 1
session.bug_compat_warn = 1

; Check HTTP Referer to invalidate externally stored URLs containing ids.
; HTTP_REFERER has to contain this substring for the session to be
; considered as valid.
session.referer_check =

; How many bytes to read from the file.
session.entropy_length = 0

; Specified here to create the session id.
session.entropy_file =

;session.entropy_length = 16

;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom

; Set to {nocache,private,public,} to determine HTTP caching aspects
; or leave this empty to avoid sending anti-caching headers.
session.cache_limiter = nocache

; Document expires after n minutes.
session.cache_expire = 180

; trans sid support is disabled by default.
; Use of trans sid may risk your users security.
; Use this option with caution.
; - User may send URL contains active session ID
;   to other person via. email/irc/etc.
; - URL that contains active session ID may be stored
;   in publically accessible computer.
; - User may access your site with the same session ID
;   always using URL stored in browser's history or bookmarks.
session.use_trans_sid = 0

; The URL rewriter will look for URLs in a defined set of HTML tags.
; form/fieldset are special; if you include them here, the rewriter will
; add a hidden <input> field with the info which is otherwise appended
; to URLs.  If you want XHTML conformity, remove the form entry.
; Note that all valid entries require a "=", even if no value follows.
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="
```

All PHP files start with session_start();
Here's a snippet of the PHP file passing the variables (POST1.PHP)

```
<?php
session_start();
//Multiple processing statements not copied
//Obtain the primary key from the prior insert
$family_fkey = mysqli_insert_id($link);
//store the value of $family_fkey into the session variable 'family_fkey'
$_SESSION["family_fkey"] = $family_fkey;
//store the value of $family_last_name into the session variable 'family_last_name'
$_SESSION["family_last_name"] = $family_last_name;
//Close the connection
mysqli_close($link);
//Redirect to the submitted.php page
header("Location: http://example.org/my_app/input2.php");
//close PHP
?>
```

Here's a snippet of the PHP file receiving the variables (INPUT2.PHP)

```
<?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- Multiple HTML and PHP Processing statements NOT copied here -->
<?php
    ECHO "Session ID is: " . session_id() . "<br />"; 
    // retrieve the session value 'family_fkey' and store it in $family_fkey
    $family_fkey = $_SESSION['family_fkey'];
    // retrieve the session value 'family_last_name' and store it in $family_last_name
    $family_last_name = $_SESSION['family_last_name'];
    ECHO "The family_last_name and family_fkey are: " . 
          $family_last_name . $family_fkey . "<br />";
```

When Input2.php is executed on my home PC, all the values echo just fine.
When Input2.php is executed on many other PC's, I get a value for the Session ID, but the two values 'family_fkey' and 'family_last_name' values are blank.  This is going to be a public-facing application.
Why do the variables pass OK for some PC's and not for others?
Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Try `session_write_close` before `header`

Comment: session_write_close() is a good idea.  PHP session behavior has changed from release to release.  In particular, at some PHP levels, if the session is unchanged, it does not get rewritten, and this can cause the session to appear to expire prematurely.  It's a good practice any time, not just in AJAX scripts.  php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Hi Ray,  Thanks very much for replying.I added "session_write_close();" before the "header" statement of POST1.PHP.  I still have the same results.

Comment: UPDATE:  It works fine on all PC's with Chrome and I.E.  It's Firefox that's giving me the problem.  It's really odd that the Firefox browser on my home PC works fine, but not on others.  Since this app will be public-facing, I can't control which browsers will be used.  I may give up on the SESSION approach and pass the two variables in the URL.